# Visualstudio 2012 Ultimate -> Coded Ui testing for website

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am working in visualstudio 2012 Ultimate with Coded Ui testing for website.I need custom changes in the recorded process.But when i recorded the new coded Ui test,then i am getting custom changes automatically deleted.

Please help me. I shall be highly thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your "custom changes" refers to edits made in the **uimap.designer.cs** file. This file is regenerated from the **uimap.uitest** file whenever new actions are recorded and whenever the uimap editor is used. There is a comment at the top of the **uimap.designer.cs** file warning that changes will be lost.

Many changes needed to the **uimap.designer.cs** file can actually be made using the uimap editor in Visual Studio (it is also available in Visual Studio 2010 feature pack 1). Double click on the **uimap.uitest** file in Solution Explorer. There are a few edit operation available by right clicking or via the 9 icons above the "UI Actions" panel. More changes can be made via the Properties of all UI Actions and their steps, also via the properties of the UI Controls.

If the changes needed cannot be made within the uimap editor then select "Move code to **uimap.cs**" (right click or it is one of the 9 icons). Exit the uimap editor, saving changes. Then edit the code as required within the **uimap.cs** file.

Note that the **uimap.designer.cs** and **uimap.cs** files both contribute to the same class, they both say **partial class**.